# Electric wiring color codes: BROWN, BLUE and BLACK

Tags: wiring, home-installation

31.01.2018 16:40 start /
Thank you all for the answers, because this is not a standard wiring plug, i need assistance wiing the wifi adapter in the middle of cable which connect the energy master expert lcd display to the energy master expert plug.
 Is this correct?

WIFI ADAPTER LIVE IN = Energy master expert PLUG BROWN live wire

WIFI ADAPTER LIVE OUT = Energy master expert LCD DISPLAY BROWN live wire

WIFI ADAPTER NEUTRAL IN = Energy master expert PLUG BLUE neutral wire

WIFI ADAPTER NEUTRAL OUT = Energy master expert LCD DISPLAY BLUE neutral wire

WIFI ADAPTER EARTH IN = Energy master expert PLUG BLACK wire

WIFI ADAPTER EARTH OUT = Energy master expert LCD DISPLAY BLACK  wire

\ end 31.01.2018 16:40

31.01.2018 16:36 start / Update from customer service:
**The Ground Line is bridged in the connector
The meter does not require a Ground Line in the cable.
Blue is the Null Line  and black and brown are the Live Line

Should you have further questions, please feel free to contact us via email.

Yours sincerely

ELV Elektronik AG

Technical customer service department** \ end 31.01.2018 16:36

Which colors are Ground Line, Null Line and Live Line? 
The standard says the Ground line is always green-yellow.
None of these wires is green-yellow. Thanks.

[image: which color is L, N, E]

---

update
If black is Earth, then why the on off switch button is using the black wire? [image: If black is Earth, then why the on off switch button is using the black wire?]

[image: the kit]

[image: instructions]

Because the cable is too short , less than 2 meters, i want to extend it. I also want to join the cables with a wifi adapter SONOFF® POW 16A 3500W DIY WIFI Wireless Long Distance APP Remote Control Switch Socket Power Monitor Current Tester For Smart Home 80-160MHz AC 90-250V Support 2G/3G/4G Network.
 That is why i need to know exactly which colors are Live, Null and Earth.
[image: sonoff instructions]

[image: sonoff photo]

Comment: Which standard? This may be country/region specific.

Comment: Germany, this plus is a part from energy master expert kit 2. I only received instructions in German, in black and white. I tried translating the wiring part, but none identified the colors fir L,N and E.

Comment: The manual shows blue as `N`. The other two wires are *both* L, black is mains->ELV and brown is ELV->consumer device. The plug has no connection to PE, other than the two prongs for schuko - but those don't go into the electronics box.

Comment: The great thing about standards is there are so many of them to choose from.

Comment: Isn't black switched live in Europe?

Comment: So many wiring colour standards, all of them useless (not obvious, difficult to see in low light, not readable by the colour-blind, not able to be explained logically). The only colours that meet all of those conditions are white for live/hot, grey for neutral, and black for ground. Sigh!

Comment: @Neil_UK: In North America, Black is live/hot, white is Neutral, and Green is safety ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combined plug/socket. The ground prongs are connected internally, no wire needed. You have to connect the blue wire to the (also internally connected) neutral screw. The brown and black wires go to the other plug/socket screws, it's live in/live out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fowm8v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks, i know from the German instruction, each wire where it goes. Now please answer this question: Which colors are Ground Line, Null Line and Live Line?

Comment: Please see my schematic. Don't know if the brown wire goes to plug and the black to the socket or vice versa – nothing bad happens if you swapped them, if the reading on the measurement device is negative, swap those wires.

Comment: Your explanation makes sens. Still, can you please explain why there is an earth clamp on the socket? Is it not connected?

Comment: The earth clamp of the plug and the socket have to be connected. Plus, Schuko sockets without earth clamp aren't allowed. There are screws on the earth clamp should your measurement (or other) device have a metal casing. You needed a four-wire cable going to it then.

Answer (score 2):

If this cable could be considered as "internal to the equipment", normal electrical code colours may not apply.

If it is a power monitor, the monitor circuit has to measure current somehow.  I suspect that R4 is the current sense resistor, and power comes in from the plug on the brown wire, and returns to the socket on the black wire.

If the instrument box has no exposed metal parts, it would have no need for a Safety Ground connection.

Comment: "If the instrument box has no exposed metal parts, it would have no need for a Safety Ground connection." Except to connect the ground through to the connected equipment?

Comment: @RoyC - but that ground connection would be in the plug/socket, with no need for a wire to the instrument.

Answer (score 0):

It depends specifically where you live, but usually you find Ground Line as Green-Yellow, Null Line as Blue and Live Line as Red, Gray, Black or Brown.

Comment: So:
LIVE: BROWN
NEUTRAL: BLUE
EARTH: BLACK

Comment: It's a combined plug/socket.

Comment: Never seen one of these, thank you for clarifying. But just searched for it, and the order should be the same as well, otherwise it would make no sense

Comment: If Black is Earth/Safety Ground, there should not be a switch in it.

Comment: Actually you´re right, but in plugs the middle conductor is usually the protective earth.

Comment: If black is Earth, then why the on/off switch button is using the black wire?

Comment: Yeah it seems weird after all. But in most plugs the central screw is connected to the earth, which I assumed to the first pic you showed.

Comment: The remote displays only works when all 3 wires are connected. Without BLACK EARTH connected, the display does not work.

Comment: Are the wires already connected? Because it seems to have been a mistaken with the wire colors. If they are already connected, which of them would match the plug you will attach it to? By doing that, the wires to the sides are the Live and Neutral, and the remaining one should be the earth

Comment: The display i assume should work without EARTH connected. The LCD POWER display to reflect the power consumption only works when all 3 wires are connected. If i leave only black disconnected, the display does not work.  If i leave only blue disconnected, the display does not work.

Comment: So I´m really sorry about it, because I thought the first pic showing the black one going to the central conductor would show the ground, as it´s in all plugs. I´m goint to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You will have the [german standard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederspannungsnetz#Farbgebung). But your application is not a standard plug.

Brown will be live.
Blue will be neutral.
Green/Yellow must be earth.
Black can be another phase, or a switched live. Or something else, black is the trivial color.

In your measurement plug, only one line is passed trough the measurement circuit. Brown -> measurement -> Black.
Neutral is passed to the measurement as well to provide voltage measurement and supply.

Earth is not required, and thus not wired, since thee enclosure of the measurement device is plastic.

Comment: IMO the best would be to take a multimeter to look which wire goes where.